# Checking if destination file already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

**Goal**

To check if a file with a same name exists in two folders (src and destination folder)

**Attempt**
Tried using `grunt-contrib-copy` to traverse the path but obviously this is not working.

```
copy: {
  unit: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src',
    src: '**',
    dest: 'specs/unit',
    filter: function(filepath){
      if(grunt.file.exists(filepath)){
        return grunt.file.write(filepath,'');
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**My Theory**

`grunt.file.exists` seems to be pointing to the src folder instead of destination folder. So it never checks if the files in src folder actually exists in the destination folder it just checks if there are any files in src folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `fs.existsSync()`: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback. Be sure to use the sync one, Grunt doesn't like async functions.

Also; make sure you return a boolean.

At the top of your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

In your task settings;

```
copy: {
  unit: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'src',
    src: '**',
    dest: 'specs/unit',
    filter: function(filepath){
      return !fs.existsSync(filepath);
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Doesn't this actually check the *destination* folder as to whether the file exists or not, or the 'src' folder? It seems to check the 'src' folder.

Comment: Seems to be checking src, rather then dest

Answer (score 0):

grunt.file.setBase('./destination')

// check for file

grunt.file.setBase('./src')

// check for file